# How to create a listview from multiple arrays?

Tags: android, arrays, listview

Good day!
I create adapter for spinner choice of fish, but the list is very long (about 1,000 items), and is an error on slower devices. Do I need an adapter to form three different resources for 350  items:

- R.array.fish1 (350 items)
- R.array.fish2 (350 items)
- R.array.fish3 (350 items)?

If this fixes my problem?

```
adapterfish = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.fish, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

***LogCat***

```
10-30 19:39:16.234: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3242 objects / 284416 bytes in 56ms    
10-30 19:39:16.304: W/dalvikvm(333): ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)    
10-30 19:39:16.304: W/dalvikvm(333): Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:    
10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   502: 0x44f89ed0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)    
10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   503: 0x44f89f30 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   504: 0x44f89f98 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   505: 0x44f8a0a8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   506: 0x44f8a100 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   507: 0x44f8a158 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   508: 0x44f8a1b0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   509: 0x44f8a200 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   510: 0x44f8a338 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.314: W/dalvikvm(333):   511: 0x44f8a388 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333): JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333):     3 of Ljava/lang/Class; 164B (2 unique)

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333):   487 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (487 unique)

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333):    20 of Ljava/lang/String; 36B (20 unique)

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 28B

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 2292B

10-30 19:39:16.324: W/dalvikvm(333): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 17004 bytes

**10-30 19:39:16.324: E/dalvikvm(333): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)**

10-30 19:39:16.324: I/dalvikvm(333): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE

10-30 19:39:16.324: I/dalvikvm(333):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0

10-30 19:39:16.324: I/dalvikvm(333):   | sysTid=333 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008

10-30 19:39:16.324: I/dalvikvm(333):   | schedstat=( 3126333106 1444170201 377 )

10-30 19:39:16.324: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(Native Method)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceStringArray(AssetManager.java:186)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:381)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at com.drchernj.petdiary.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:143)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-30 19:39:16.334: I/dalvikvm(333):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

10-30 19:39:16.344: I/dalvikvm(333):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

10-30 19:39:16.344: I/dalvikvm(333):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

10-30 19:39:16.344: I/dalvikvm(333):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-30 19:39:16.344: E/dalvikvm(333): VM aborting

10-30 19:39:17.694: I/Lang change(339): Locale=en

10-30 19:39:18.155: D/dalvikvm(339): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3510 objects / 198664 bytes in 61ms
```

Thank you very much for your help and support!

Comment: The size of the array shouldn't cause an error unless it was running out of memory, which doesn't seem likely.  What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: my emulator says that is not enough memory and real-phone Application crashes

Comment: An array of 1000 Strings isn't likely to crash the device, you probably have another error in your code. You should create a new question, provide a proper explanation and post the stacktrace.